Will native speaker understand us
Yesterday i got an answer and i was not clear that that's why i am asking this .By means of this site I get understood about since. We are non native speakers , so we don't know like native speaker. We can try to understand English that we can afford. Here I want to ask that will native speaker understand that if we imitate their words. Definition of since,
since - an event in the past that marked the beginning of the period, and then the action or state that either exists or continues in the present.
According to definition and usages of some sentences ,for example

It is five years since I was in London.
I am a lot happier since I left the job.

Here,my example

I have lived with my parents since I was born.(Naturally and Grammatical)

If I say
#3. I live with my parents since I was born.
Will native speakers understand me that i am trying to say I lived with my parents and still live now since I was born by using definition of since.

I have behaved in good manner since I was a child.(Grammartically , I don't know naturally)

If I say
#4. I behave in good manner since I was a child.
Will native speakers understand me that i am trying to say I behaved in good manner as a child and still behave in good manner now by using definition of since.
In our country , there is a law for marriage that a man can marry a girl one time in his life. If his wife pass away then he can marry another girl. But in the course of marriage a man can't marry one more girls. If he marries one more girls then he must be arrested. We accept that law as a culture.
I want to say that situation as follow

We have accepted marriage's law since government declared it.(grammatically ,I don't know naturally)

If I say
#5. We accept marriage's law since government declared it.
Will native speakers understand me that i am trying to say we accepted marriage's law and still accept  now that law  by using definition of since.
If I say #3,#4 and #5 will native speaker understand me? Please just make a note "yes" or "no".

(3) is correct. A native speaker would understand (#3), but saying it that way would make it obvious that you don't speak English at all well.

Yes ,thank you madam , you are always helping me.I promise I won't use those expressions because I am non native speaker because I don't understand that "it is five years since ". I will always use present perfect with since. You are so understanding learners. @Kate Bunting

The duplicate covers the first point but there are a lot of different questions here. You should ask them separately.

Bigamy (being married to more than one person at the same time) is against the law in many countries! We have accepted the law against bigamy since the government passed it.
